# error: name 'Image' not defined

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to transpose all the images inside a folder and trying to execute this code:

```
import os

import glob

path = 'C:/Users/mail2/Desktop/flippin/pics/'
i = 0

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):

    img = Image.open(infile)
    print ("current file is: " + infile)
    img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
    img.transpose(
        Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).transpose(
        Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).save("combined%s.jpg")
print('done')
```

but i keept getting `name 'image' not defined error.`

Please help. Thanks !!

Comment: did my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531132/4879665 help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you didn't define `Image` to do that just import `Image` from the `PIL` module. To accomplish this just add this line to your code: `from PIL import Image`:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import glob

path = 'C:/Users/mail2/Desktop/flippin/pics/' i = 0

for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):

img = Image.open(infile)
print ("current file is: " + infile)
img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
img.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
img.transpose(
    Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).transpose(
    Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).save("combined%s.jpg")

print('done')
```

Comment: Thanks...was quite a simple mistake